# Issue in deploying facebook integrated application on android device

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I developed one facebook integrated android application. I followed all the steps as mentioned on the facebook developer site. My application is running very well on the emulator but the same application does not run on the device. When I click login button it shows loading message and message disappears and do not proceed.
I spend 2 days on the same issue.
If I delete facebook app for android from the device then it works very well, but that is not the good option.
I created new appId and assigned new keyhash to the application. I debug my application using adb logcat but it did not show me device specific  keyhash. I am using latest facebook sdk. 
I faced the same problem before. Last time I use adb logcat command to watch what is going wrong and I got device specific keyhash . I entered that keyhash on the developer site in native android app column and my app started working nice on the device irrespective of facebook app installed on device or not. I used  that app id for my new application but it is still not working. I also signed my apk file and then tried on device , still not working.
I am not able to figure out what is the exact problem.   Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

If facebook app. is installed on your phone, you should process responce in

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `facebook_object.logout(Application_Context);` in the `onComplete` callback method:

```
public void onComplete(Bundle values) {     
  //code for what needs to be done

  // after your code 
  facebook_object.logout(Application_Context);
}
```

This should log your account out from applications and when you return it will ask you to log in again.